# Vaadin Editable ComboBox with default options

Tags: java, javascript, html, vaadin

I'm new Vaadin developer and I'm having a little problem that I hope can resolve here.

Actually I have a one combobox with some data with one filter that find some matches so... I need to enter new values of user that needs in the combobox. The problem is I can't enter new values, because when I do my filter is deleting my new proposal.

My code...

```
    //Select select_editable = new Select();
    ComboBox cbEducation = new ComboBox();
    cbEducation.setTextInputAllowed(true);
    cbEducation.setNewItemsAllowed(true);
    cbEducation.setFilteringMode(AbstractSelect.Filtering.FILTERINGMODE_CONTAINS);
    //Fill the component with some items.
    for (int i = 0; i < planets.length; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < planets.length; j++) {
            cbEducation.addItem(planets[j] + " to " + planets[i]);
        }
    //select_editable.
    mainLayout.addComponent(cbEducation, 1, 0);
    mainLayout.setComponentAlignment(cbEducation, new Alignment(33));
```

I hope someone can help me... anyways thanks for reading

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want see the new entered values immediately after you entered them you have to set the combobox immediate mode to true.

```
cbEducation.setImmediate(true);
```

Be careful if you use the VisualDesigner to create your Layouts. It will set all components immediate state to false. hopefully this nice tool will get an update soon.

Comment: ComboBox in Vaadin 7.2+ is immediate by default.

Comment: Totally done. I don't know why I not tried this, thank you so much!

Comment: Many Components are immediate by default. But if you use the Visual Designer to create your layouts. it will set immediate to false. Seems like the visualdesigner is a little outdated.